# Create a non-collection resource in Eve

Tags: python, eve

As you know, when creating a resource in the domain named, say "people", you get a collection resource with the following behaviour:

- `GET /people` returns the collection
- `POST /people` adds to the collection
- `GET /people/{id}` returns a single resource in the collection.

What I want to do is create a resource named, say "foobar", that is not a collection, such that:

- `GET /foobar` will return a single resource (e.g. `{"foo":true, "bar": false}` )
- `PUT /foobar` will upsert the one and only foobar resource.

Something like this:

```
DOMAIN = {
  'people': {
    'schema': {'firstName': {'type': 'string'}, 'lastName': {'type': 'string'}}
  },
  'foobar': {
    'schema': {'foo': {'type': 'boolean'}, 'bar': {'type': 'boolean'}},
    'singleton': True  # does something like this exist?
  }
}
```

What I've done for now is create flask routes for GET and PUT, but I have to hand-code all of the automatic goodness Eve provides.

Is there a way to create a non-collection resource in the domain?

Comment: Why not take the other way around the problem? Let eve do it's thing. Provide a custom `DataLayer` implementation that can handle your case. There maybe some gotchas, but I would advise to try that first.